# Error When Compiling on Eclipse Luna with JavaCC - Could not find or load main class javacc

Tags: eclipse, parsing, eclipse-plugin, lexical-analysis, javacc

I downloaded JavaCC to my eclipse Luna using this link as guideline - http://homepages.gac.edu/~hvidsten/courses/MC270/Labs/project4-GacApplication/project-files/JavaCC/JavaCC-Eclipse.html

Ive read version 6 has problems but I think this is version 5. I have also added javaCC jar folders as a reference lib

However when I try to compile my .jj code by clicking compile with javacc it doesn't work and gives the error - Could not find or load main class javacc

I've tried adding the bin folder from my javacc to my pathway but I had no luck

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 7):

In your project properties, find the JavaCC Projects Options.  Set the JavaCC jar file either to blank or to the following (changing the version number if need be).
[image]

Comment: If that doesn't work, try updating the JavaCC plugin to the latest version and set the jar file option mentioned in the answer to blank.

Answer (score 1):

If you work in Windows:

Find the JavaCC Projects Options. Set the path of JavaCC.jar file with backslashes to:

```
...eclipse\plugins\sf.eclipse.javacc_1.5.30\jars\javacc-5.0.jar
```